# Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio on a VM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mono, xamarin-studio

I will be starting my final year project for my degree soon and am aiming to create a web application with an ASP.NET C# front-end and a SOAP (or REST, haven't fully decided yet) web service back-end. I will be developing on my MacBook, which poses the problem with ASP.NET being a Microsoft framework and Visual Studio not being available for Mac OS, so I have turned to the Mono framework and its IDE, Xamarin Studio.

I have created a very, very basic SOAP web service which can be found [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html), deployed it to glassfish and can navigate to the wsdl. 
The problems start when I try and consume the web service from Xamarin Studio, I can get the proxy set up fine and I have created a very simple page that should display the result of calling the `add` web method. The markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="TryItOutNetApplication.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click me!" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
        Hey, the result of 1 + 2 is: 
        <asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code-behind:

```
namespace TryItOutNetApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using localhost;

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private FYPTestWebService ws;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ws = new localhost.FYPTestWebService();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = ws.add(1,2);
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }

        public void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            button1.Text = "You clicked me";
        }
    }
}
```

I then get the following error when I try and run the application:

```
Application Exception
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Connection reset by peer

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.
Exception stack trace: 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result) [0x0002d] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1816 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x0002f] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:32
```

I have not been able to find any help for Xamarin Studio and it generally seems pretty awful compared to Visual Studio.

My question is

a) am I just doing something stupid with my above code/setup?

b) should I scrap Mono/Xamarin Studio and use something like VirtualBox to install Visual Studio and use that instead?

Comment: if you don't need mobile, why use Xamarin, you can use MonoDevelop: http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: That's where I first went as I had heard of MonoDevelop, but when I select the Mac OSX download link it downloads a Xamarin dmg

Comment: yes, right, Xamarin offers a rebranded version of MonoDevelop 4.0 as Xamarin Studio.

Comment: So does that mean there is a way to have the "vanilla" MonoDevelop 4.0 and if so, is it any better than Xamarin Studio?

Comment: I don't know, never used MonoDevelop; just tried Xamarin Studio on Windows for mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

The point is: where will your application finally has to be: in a Windows Server or a Linux Server
(or in other words: in a .NET framework or a Mono framework).

It's not that you cannot develop in one framework and deploy to other, but if you develop in the same framework where it has to finally run you will have less surprises!

Also, you can work with the same project in Visual Studio and Xamarin/Monodevelop  at the same time (well, maybe with a little of solution file overwriting battle...)
.

Comment: I am yet to decide whether deploying to a web server will also be in the scope of my project. I was more focusing on the fact that I am using technologies we had not been taught as part of the course, such as the .NET, web services, application servers, continuous integration servers and integration testing.

Comment: Its not related to the question but I will recommend (of course, if you can choose) forgot about Asp.Net and learn Asp.MVC

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest installing Visual studio to a virtual machine on your Mac, it makes much more sense to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should consider developing directly in Visual Studios 2013 it works like a champ using VMWare Fusion. there is a bridge that connects the simulator called Xamarin iOS Build Host, once that connects you will be ready to code!